# C++ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::replace: __pos

Tags: c++

I am working on a project for school and I am asked to input a string and it will convert the string to "leet speak". In my program I take the user input and then pass it to a method that searches an array for each character in the string. When it finds the character it replaces it with the appropriate character from a second array. I am having an issue related to the size of my array and the user input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void leetTranslate(string input) {
  int length = input.length();
  cout << length;
  char normalLetters[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
  string leetLetters[26] = {"4","B","(","D","3","Ph","9","|-|","1","j","|<","L","/\\/\\","|\\| ","0","P","Q",
  "R","$","7","U","\\/","\\/\\/","><","'/","Z"};

  for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
      if (input[j] == normalLetters[i]) {
        input.replace(j,1,leetLetters[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  cout << input;
  

}

int main() {
  string userInput;
  cout << "Enter a string: ";
  getline(cin, userInput);

  leetTranslate(userInput);
}
```

It produces the error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what():  basic_string::replace: __pos (which is 116) > this->size() (which is 4)`

Comment: [`std::string::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace)

Comment: And let me guess, the input you give the program starts with `t`, which have the ASCII encoded value of `116`. Now try to read the error message again.

Answer (score 1):

On you line:

```
input.replace(input[j],1,leetLetters[i]);
```

The signature for `replace` is `str.replace(size::t pos, size::t count, string str2)`

`pos` is the index number of character in your string where you want to start replacing. And right now you are passing in the first `char` from `input`, which is probably `'t'`. `'t'` would be converted to number `116`, which is way larger than the size of your string, which is why it throws out of range.

So if you want to replace the first letter to the corresponding string, you would do:

```
input.replace(j, 1, leetLetters[i]);
```

---

#### Edit:

About the problem that your function stop in the middle is because your first `for` loop `for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)`.

Note that in here `length` never changed, even you might have actually changed the length of your `input`. For instance, if there's a `'w'` in your input, then it will be changed to `"\/\/"`, which adds 3 more `char` into your `input`. So if your input was `"what"`, your length would be `4`. After changing `'w'`, it would become `"\/\/hat"`. Your function only replace till the `length`th character, so `"hat"` would remain unchanged.

Instead what you could do is just past in `input.length()` in the for loop, so it would be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++)
```

Also note this only work if you replacement letters does not overlap with your normal letters, if they do overlap, you would want to add an increment to `j` inside the function by `leetLetters[i].length() - 1`, so you would add `j += leetLetters[i].length() - 1` inside the function.

Comment: Yep that was it, changed it to `input.replace(j, 1, leetLetters[i]);` and that works, to a point, then it stops converting it. Any idea why?


Input:
`Enter a string: It will convert the string and then it just stops`

Output: 
`I7 \/\/1LL (0|\| \/3R7 7|-|3 $7R1|\| 9 4|\| D 7|-|en it just stops`

Comment: @JustinWilker Your index `j` was never used. Do you mean to check`if(input[j] == normalLetters[i]` and `input.replace(j, 1, leetLetters[i])`?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my post to include that, still having an issue with the program just stopping before completing the whole string

Comment: Edit: I've realized my problem comes when replacing a character with a string that has multiple chars, ie m > /\/\, this then uses up spaces in the length counter. I am unsure how to fix it though

Comment: @JustinWilker Was about to say that, check my edit in the answer

Comment: @JustinWilker Also this only work if you replacement letters does not overlap with your normal letters, if they do overlap, you would want to add an increment to `j` inside the function by `leetLetters[i].length() - 1`